# Make query_posts exclude post based on a term in the post title

Tags: wordpress

Posts on my page are fetched via this query:

```
<?php
$limit = get_option('posts_per_page');
query_posts(array(
'showposts'=>62,
'more' => $more = 0,
'v_sortby'  => 'views',
'v_orderby' => 'DESC',
'v_outtype' => 'content',
'v_timespan' => 'year',
'paged' => $paged
));?>               
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

However, I want to exclude all posts which title contains the word "Metal".
I know there's a `'post__not_in' =>`  feature, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

I tried

`$exclude1 = get_page_by_title('Metal');`  and then including

```
 'post__not_in' => array($exclude1->ID,$exclude2->ID)
```

but that seems to center around pages, and not post titles itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the arguments:

```
$args['special_search'] = 'Metal';
```

In your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'special_search_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function special_search_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
    if (isset($query->query_vars["special_search"])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title NOT LIKE \'%' . $query->query_vars["special_search"] . '%\'';
    }

    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Nothing shows up if i run that, but I can see what you mean. I'll research a bit based on a meta_query.

Comment: I tried locally my solution and it seems impossible to make a meta_query on the title of a post. Since, I edited my answer for an other solution.

Comment: Merci beucoup, i'll try to get it to work. At the moment the functions.php code throws out: PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.=' (T_CONCAT_EQUAL) in your code on line 5 ,   but i'll keep trying a few possibilities.